# Hector slam mapping

Tags: hector-slam, ros-noetic, hector-mapping, depthimage-to-laserscan

I'm currently converting depth image to laserscan, further i want to do mapping using hector slam . When i try running my code it say.

> lookupTransform base_link to camera_depth_frame timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.

Can anyone please help me with this .
thanks in advance.
please find my launch file script below

```
<launch>
<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
    <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
 <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
 <remap from="scan" to="/scan"/> 
 </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_odom" args="1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1  map odom 10000" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_bf" args="1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1  odom base_footprint 10000" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="bf_bl" args="1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1  base_footprint base_link 10000" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="bl_scan" args="1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1 base_link  scan 10000 "/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="bl_cdf" args="1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1  base_link  camera_depth_frame 10000" />
</launch>
```

Comment: after i replace 1000 from 10000 everthing was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after i replace 1000 from 10000 everything was fine

Glad you figured it out, but you'd be better off using the `static_transform_publisher` from the `tf2_ros` package instead. With this newer improved node, you don't specify a period_in_millisec at all:

```
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="myname" args="x y z yaw pitch roll parent_frame child_frame" />
```

Comment: thank you so much